# Will someone please merge tags [c3js] and [c3.js]?

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Clearly the [c3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3js) and [c3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3.js) tags reference the same library. I suggest [c3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c3.js) be kept.

Comment: Agh some of the questions have both tags so people knew about this! If no one has any issues we can go through those 45 questions pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Poof! Done. Happy New Year!

Tag remapping of [c3.js] and [c3js] complete!