# Merge [p5.js] tag into [p5js] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

P5.js is a library that I'm highly active on, but when I started out of Stack Overflow I tried using the [p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5js) tag and it failed, I was convinced for a year or so that the p5.js library wasn't supported on Stack Overflow.

I think the [p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5.js) tag should be merged with [p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5js).

Comment: I added some markdown to your post for the tags but did not change the content. Your initial request in the question (as formatted initially) was "I think the [p5.js] tag should be merged with [p5.js]." but those are the same tags. To clarify are you proposing a synonym [tag:p5js] ->[tag:p5.js] or the other way around (as stated in the title)? There are also no questions in [tag:p5js] so there's nothing to merge.

Comment: If your request is indeed to rename the [p5.js] tag to [p5js] (which your title requests, as a merge into a non-existent tag is a rename): we should not do that, because the name of the library is "p5.js".

Comment: Oops, sorry. Yes its to merge [p5.js] tag to [p5js] tag. I edited the post.

Answer (score 7):

We should not rename this tag [p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5js).

The primary reason is, as [Ryan mentioned](/posts/comments/918065), the library is called [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) on their official site. The dot is part of the name. Creating a tag that is incorrectly named and making it the primary one does not make sense.

Additionally, we have a long standing precedent using the ".js" form for JavaScript library tags (inline with the library's official names).

Some examples of adding or fixing tags in favour of ".js":

- [Merge tag [ml5] into [ml5.js]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418011/15497888)
- [Duplicate tags: [vue.js] and [vue-js]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318023/15497888)
- [Merge [tensorflow-js] and [tensorflow.js] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372724/15497888)
- [Will someone please merge tags [c3js] and [c3.js]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281489/15497888)
- [Make [interact-js] a synonym of [interact.js]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342187/15497888)

*etc.*

See also the existing [[*.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*.js%5D) tags.

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Having said this, however, I would support a synonym going the other way [p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5js) -> [p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5.js).

There are (currently) 106 questions that contain "p5js" that do not have the [p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5.js) ([is:q "p5js" -[p5.js]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22p5js%22+-%5Bp5.js%5D))

We *do* have a precedent of making these synonyms *e.g.*:

- [nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) -> [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)
- [vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vuejs) -> [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)
- [nuxtjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxtjs) -> [nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nuxt.js)

*etc.*

It's not possible to say whether these questions did not use the tag because they looked for it and [couldn't find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO0Le.png) (as supported in the question) or for some other nebulous reasons, however, making this synonym would accomplish a similar goal to make [p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5.js) more discoverable through [p5js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p5js).

Comment: Synonym [p5js] -> [p5.js] [meta-tag:status-completed]: Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/419167/6